# Execute a jquery function onchange of ddslick option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a jquery function on change of options in ddslick dropdown...

```
$("select[name=ddslick_select]").change(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

I am using the name of the select to get the value changed event. So that on change of the value of that name will be recognised. But, I couldn't execute the function.

Comment: Could you share the exact code you're using on jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Provide your html to?

Answer (score 1):

Note that [ddslick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) also provides its own callbacks:

```
$('input[name=ddslick_select]').ddslick({
    // other options...
    onSelected: function(data){
        alert("changed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not helping, `<input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" name="ddslick_name" value="4w">` this is the field which is storing the value of ddslick select option.. So, I think, input[name=ddslick_name'] will do the work

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala: What's "not helping" is that you aren't providing the HTML code that you're asking about.  Either way, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Even the above code is not working, I've tried calling with `id` value too

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala: Can you provide a complete example of the problem in the question?  "not working" isn't really a meaningful problem description.

Comment: @VyshnaviSamudrala: There is *a lot* of code there.  How much of that is related to the question at all?  Nobody here is going to debug *all of that* for you.  But one thing I can't help but notice is that there *is no* `input[name=ddslick_select]` in your HTML.  Which would probably be why it "doesn't work".  An HTML element has to exist before you can attach an event handler to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121724/discussion-between-vyshnavi-samudrala-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

The select changes, the option does not -

```
 $('.classOfTheSelectElement').on('change', function(){
  alert($(this).val());
 });
```

see if this alerts your selected options value

Answer (score 0):

User `select` instead of `input` for dropdown:

```
$("select[name='ddslick_select']").change(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

or simply use `name` attribute:

```
$("[name='ddslick_select']").change(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ddSlick implements a Callback for that

```
$("#myDiv").ddslick({
    data: ddData,
    defaultSelectedIndex: 3,
    onSelected: function (data) {
        alert("change");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution

```
$("select.ddslick").each(function() {
$(this).ddslick({
    onSelected: function(data){
        console.log(data.selectedData.value);
    }
});

});
```